# OrientDB restore -> database is closed

Tags: orientdb

I have a `db.zip` archive (with .cpm, .pcl, .irs,.sbt, .wal, ... files) I like to restore

```
create database plocal:mydb admin admin
restore database /path/to/db.zip

Restoring database database /path/to/db.zip...
- Uncompressing file $FILE1_IN_ARCHIVE [...snip...]
- [...snip...]
Database restored in 0.19 seconds
```

To me, it seems as the restore was successful. However, whatever next command I use (e.g. `select * from V`) I get the following error:

```
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Database 'mydb' is closed
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why is the DB closed? How could I open it?

Comment: Hi, did you execute an `EXPORT` or a `BACKUP` of your original DB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your case with OrientDB version 2.1.11 following these steps (previously I created a backup copy of a DB with the new name `mydb.zip`).

1. Create the new DB:

   ```
   create database plocal:/path/to/db/newDB admin admin

   Creating database [plocal:/path/to/db/newDB] using the storage type [plocal]...

   Database created successfully.
   ```
2. Restore `mydb.zip`:

   ```
   restore database C:/path/to/db/mydb.zip

   Restoring database database C:/path/to/db/mydb.zip...
   ...
   Database restored in 0,29 seconds
   ```
3. Select all vertices from `V` (I get your same exception):

   ```
   orientdb {db=newDB}> select * from V

   Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Database 'newDB'
          is closed
   ```

This (your) problem seems to be related to this [issue](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4787) where it's explained that the access to a DB in `plocal` mode with another running OrientDB instance generates a conflict.
If you shutdown the opened OrientDB instance and try to connect to the DB in `plocal` mode, you'll be able to access to the DB.

1. Shutdown the running OrientDB instance and re-connect in `plocal` mode:

   ```
   orientdb> connect plocal:/path/to/db/newDB admin admin

   Connecting to database [plocal:/path/to/db/newDB] with user 'admin'...OK
   ```
2. Select again all vertices from `V`:

   ```
   orientdb {db=newDB}> select * from V

   ----+-----+-------+------+--------
   #   |@RID |@CLASS |name  |category
   ----+-----+-------+------+--------
   0   |#12:0|Station|First |#13:0
   1   |#12:1|Station|Second|#13:1
   2   |#12:2|Station|Third |#13:2
   ----+-----+-------+------+--------
   ```

Anyway, I tried also with the new **OrientDB 2.2.0 beta** and, with this version, this behaviour doesn't happen:

```
    Restoring database 'database C:/path/to/db/mydb.zip' from full backup...
    ...
    Database restored in 0,75 seconds

    orientdb {db=newDB}> select * from V

    ----+-----+-------+------+--------
    #   |@RID |@CLASS |name  |category
    ----+-----+-------+------+--------
    0   |#12:0|Station|First |#13:0
    1   |#12:1|Station|Second|#13:1
    2   |#12:2|Station|Third |#13:2
    ----+-----+-------+------+--------
```

Hope it helps

Comment: 'close' and then reconnecting worked. However, the graph was empty after restoring. For testing reasons, I did a backup & restore of the Grateful Dead db with the same effect. So, I do something completely wrong :) What worked for me, was to copy the unzipped folder to the physical folder on disk.

Comment: Hi, thanks vor voting. Anyway, which version did you use ? Have you tried with the new 2.2.0 beta ? With this last I didn't encounter this problem.